# When the company will stop production?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

Given total costs function $C(q)=100+10q-6q^2+3q^3$. For which price the company will stop production given that all of the fixed costs are sunk?
Do not know how to approach those type of questions, appreciate help.

Comment: You have any formulas involving production, fixed costs?

Comment: First, you need to find out given price p, which quantity the firm will produce, that is: $max_q P*q-(100+10q-6q^2+3q^3)$ Then, figure out at which prices profits will be negative.